# How to select PostScript printer output tray

Tags: postscript

I'm having problems with PostScript, especially the setpagedevice operator.

Goal: I want to set the pagesize, select the output tray and then do my PostScript thing. For example, for printing on A3 to tray 3, no duplex, I say

> `<</DeferredMediaSelection true /PageSize [842 1191] /ImagingBBox null /MediaClass null>> setpagedevice`
>
> `<</MediaPosition 2 /TraySwitch false>> setpagedevice`
>
> `<</Duplex false /Tumble false>> setpagedevice`

This works well initially, but when I want to switch to another source, like MPT or Tray 4 or so, the printer suddenly always wants to use the manual paper tray. Somehow I must be leaving state on the printer.

More Info: Actually, the problem is this: If the Paper Source on the printer is set to Auto Select, the above code works fine. If the Paper Source on the printer is set to something else, the above code does not work

Comment: Setting the paper source on the printer's panel (or via the printer's web interface) overrides settings embedded in the PostScript file.

Comment: What kind of printer do you have?  When you say "the Paper Source on the printer is set...", what action are you taking -- pushing front panel buttons? Selecting option in printer control panel web page? What does that printer's documentation say about which takes precedence, the PostScript language paper source setting or the front panel buttons or the printer's control panel web page?

Answer (score 0):

PJL (Printer Job Language) may be your answer. [Discussion](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=584680) & [Documentation](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/bpl13208/bpl13208.pdf).